What is the purpose of this circuit on the PIC16F18345 Evaluation Board?
I am trying to understand the schematic of MPLAB® XPRESS PIC16F18345 EVALUATION BOARD. However, I cannot understand the following parts.

What are the components connected to the RA4 pin of the MCU (PIC16F1454) expected to do? Does this circuit have a special name?
Why is a small resistor connected to RC4 and RC5 pins of this MCU (PIC16F1454)?


This image is taken from page 27 of the document Microchip MPLAB® Xpress Evaluation Board.


Protect the RA4 from overvoltage. Some PICs are programmed with high voltage (say 12V) on target MCLR pin which the RA4 can't handle directly. I guess you could call it a clamp circuit.

To protect from two outputs from shorting together. The target may use the programming pins for other purposes like LED blinking so they become outputs on the target.


